# Why my Excel Formula made in VBA is passed with a @ sign?

Tags: excel, vba, max

I will paste here  my VBA code which is supposed to add and calculate a formula in a given range. I am using a Max If formula in my master page which technically is supposed to retrieve the last contact date in another sheet.

```
Sub LastContactDate()
Dim WsMaster As Worksheet
Dim WsLastRow As Long
Dim OutputRange As Range
Dim tmpCalc As XlCalculation: tmpCalc = Application.Calculation 'Save setting
Const OutputColumn As Long = 29 ' "AC"
Set WsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
WsLastRow = WsMaster.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set OutputRange = WsMaster.Range(WsMaster.Cells(5, OutputColumn), WsMaster.Cells(WsLastRow, OutputColumn))
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Makes things slightly faster
WsMaster.Unprotect
With OutputRange
       
      
       .Formula = "=IF(MAX(IF(ContactDate!A:A=Master!B5,ContactDate!B:B))=0,"""",MAX(IF(ContactDate!A:A=Master!B5,ContactDate!B:B)))"   'This will fill down automatically
        
  '     .Replace What:="@", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    '  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
   '   ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
        .Calculate 'Needed because Calculation is currently manual
    '  .Value = .Value 'Convert the formulae into flat values
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 32, 96)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(221, 235, 247)
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Font.Size = 11
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With
Application.Calculation = tmpCalc 'Restore setting saved earlier
End Sub
```

The formula is added into the master page column but is paste incorrectly as follows:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(**@**ContactDate!A:A=Master!B5,ContactDate!B:B))=0,"",MAX(IF(**@**ContactDate!A:A=Master!B5,ContactDate!B:B)
```

Why the @ sign is added? How can I get rid of it?

If I use the Replace part the file becomes very slow.

Thank you

Comment: Change `.Formula` to `.Formula2`.